# Как скопировать кортеж в список

Tags: python

```
def function(var, *list):
    new_list = list # вариант не работает, так как аргументы функции - кортеж
```

как скопировать значения list в new_list чтобы new_list был списком?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Назвав агрумент как `list` вы переопределили одноименный тип. Назовите его как-нибудь иначе и сможете создать список.

```
def function(var, *arg_list):
    new_list = list(arg_list)
```

Comment: Только не тип, а функцию преобразования list

Comment: @alexlz, тогда уж скорее ключевое слово, поскольку list - это не функция.

    >>> type(list)
    <type 'type'>

Но это уже лирика.

Comment: Лирика, конечно. Но из документации по Built-in functions:

    list([iterable])
    Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For instance, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, returns a new empty list, [].

Что поделаешь -- Зелёный Змий.

Comment: И? `list()` - это встроенная функция, `list` - это встроенный тип, где в моих словах противоречие? Я выше привел пример `type([]) == list`, как это по вашему работает?

PS И да, в питоне размыто понятие функций, объектов и типов.
PPS Что б не быть голословным [Data Types](http://docs.python.org/library/datatypes.html)

> Python also provides some built-in data types, in particular, dict, list, set (which along with frozenset, replaces the deprecated sets module), and tuple. The str class can be used to handle binary data and 8-bit text, and the unicode class to handle Unicode text.